# openCV undefined symbols _cvCvtColor

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I know similar questions has been posted but the solutions I found haven't worked at all for me.

I'm using XCode 4.5 and openCV 2.4.3.  I built the library from source, I have the compiler set to LLVM GCC 4.2 and whenever I try to use cvCvtColor(), I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvCvtColor referenced from:
    _main in main.o
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this for an iPhone app (running in the simulator) or an MacOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and I'm kicking myself.  It turns out I didn't import a particular library (libopencv_imgproc to be specific) that cvCvtColor() was on.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Can you accept your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal, "cd" to the directory that contains your OpenCV library (or actually libraries, as I see a few of them are built when I look at this ["how to build OpenCV tutorial"](http://www.shiffman.net/2011/01/23/how-to-build-opencv-static-libraries-mac-os-x/)) and then type in this command:

"`nm -arch x86_64 _________.a`" (fill in the name of the library where the underscores are)

This dumps out all the symbols of the library.  You can egrep or search for "`cvCvtColor`".

My guess is that you've built OpenCV for 32-bit only (and this will be easy to see if you get absolutely no symbols when specifying "`-arch x86_64`" in the "`nm`" command) and that you need to also build your OpenCV libraries for 64-bit (x86_64).

Comment: hmm...how would you go about building the library for 64-bit?  It must be possible with the latest version of CV since the entire library is apparently 64-bit compatible.  Also, it looks like the tutorial you linked to is for creating static libraries and I did build the library as a dynamic one.  Should I build it as a static library?  Thanks!